# Как формируется цвет мазка кисти в Paint?

Tags: алгоритм, графика

Появилась необходимость реализовать свою чёрную кисть, на подобие как у Paint.
Если рассмотреть точечный мазок кистью под масштабом 800%, имеем следующие (рис. 1):
[image: Рис. 1]
Мазок в виде линий (рис. 2):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вопрос - как программно формируется этот мазок\мазки? Где то видел упоминание, что цвет каждого пикселя формируется на основе соседских пикселей. Если да, то каким образом? Какая формула используется для подсчета rgb пикселя?
Очень нужно, перекопал пол Google, но безрезультатно. Пожалуйста подскажите, спасибо.

Comment: полагаю Вам можно рисовать круг радиусом 1 пиксель + обычный multisampling antialiasing

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/351706/

Comment: Спасибо, буду смотреть и копать

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо [Stranger in the Q](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/188366/stranger-in-the-q) - гуглил multisampling antialiasing и нашел веб-сайт https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/anti-aliased-line-xiaolin-wus-algorithm/

Ну и сам принцип (рис. 1):

[image: Рис. 1]